# Who is the God of Emotion?

Tags: gods, mantras, practice

Who is the God of Emotion? Are there any Mantras for emotions?

For example, what are some Mantras for good mental health, and mental and emotional strength?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion God of Emotion is `Lord Shiva`.

If you can read Sanskrit here are few mantras you can recite for good mental, physical health and emotional strength.

`अच्युतानंद गोविंद नामोच्चारणभेषजात। 
नश्यन्ति सकलारोगा: सत्यं सत्यं वदाम्यहम्।`

where `अच्युत` means the supreme unmistakable,
`अनंत` means endless,
`गोविंद` lord Krishna

So reciting the name of the unmistakably supreme and endless Lord Govind destroys all sins, disease and sorrows in life and in turn results in good mental and physical health and emotional strength.

You can also recite `Surya Stotram`preferably in the early morning, you can find it here [Pratha Smarana Surya Stotram](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Pratha_Smarana_Surya_Stotram)

Another powerful mantra is [Aditya Hriday Stotra](https://www.voidcan.org/aditya-hridaya-stotra-in-english/) which if recited correctly is very powerful and results in greater mental peace, emotional health and success in life.

Of course I'm no expert in the subject, I'm just a simple follower of Sanatan Dharma.